# User Control in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm trying to create User Control in ASP.NET MVC 5. The control name is LoginUserControl.ascx and saved in Shared folder under Views. I'm trying to call the user control in the _Layout.cshtml but it is giving error? Please suggest the right way to do it.

.ASCX Code :

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="LoginUserWebControl.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="TestApp.Views.Shared.LoginUserWebControl" %>

<%
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
%>
        Welcome <b><%: Page.User.Identity.Name %></b>!
        @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") 
<%
    }
    else {
%> 
        @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") 
<%
    }
%>
```

Adding in Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>   
       <li>@Html.Partial("LoginUserWebControl")</li>                
     </ul>
```

Error:

> The view at '~/Views/Shared/LoginUserWebControl.ascx' must derive from
>   ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or
>   ViewUserControl.
>   Blockquote

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix Webforms controls and MVC.

Comment: What you really want is to create PartialView, not an user control.

Comment: I'll try with PartialView. Thanks

Comment: Can we create usercontrol in MVC 5 and add it to any View page. Any Example

Answer (score 0):

Your LoginUserWebControl.ascx.cs must derive from the ViewUserControl like so:

```
partial class LoginUserWebControl : System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl
{
    ...
}
```